# display 2 record in one row in reactjs bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an object, I want to display 2 records in one row using Bootstrap and REACT,my code is

```
const data={
            name:"xyz",
            mobile:1234567890,
            landline:123456,
            dob:19840602,
            pan:XYZ1234BGS,
          }
 {Object.keys(data)
                  .map((key, i) => (
                    <div className="row" key={i}>
                      <div
                        className="col-sm-2"
                        style={{ fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "bold" }}
                      >
                        {key}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-4" style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>
                        {data[key]}
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

expected output -

```
name:      xyz         mobile:      1234567890  
landline:  123456      landline:    123456  
dob:       19840602    pan:         XYZ1234BGS
```

actual output -

```
 name:xyz
 mobile:1234567890
 landline:123456
 dob:19840602
 pan:XYZ1234BGS
```

Comment: Did you add Bootstrap css and js files to index.js file of react?

Comment: yes.but does it matters?

Comment: Is there any styling, or an outer container, that dictates row width? Bootstrap flexbox column widths (set by your `col-sm-x` classes) need the width to be set somewhere.